Azure PublicClientApplication WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true) - "Use another account" doesn't work
I am trying to use PublicClientApplication WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true) for user login in a WPF application.
The embedded popup displays two options

My existing account
"Use another account"

My existing account works fine.
"Use another account" asks for email id,
I enter a different email id,
it does not ask for password,
Logs in using My existing account
